# Is there a way to compare a string in an IF statement while comparing integer inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, string, int

*(Sorry in advance if there's a solution I'm maladroitly overlooking.)*

Recently I've stumbled upon something that seems somewhat simple, but I can't figure it out.
It goes as follows: If I get an input that has been converted to an int once I initialize the value receiving it (Ex. number = int(input())). Then I go on to set up an if statement that has conditions that compared if the input equals a number, is there also a way I can set a condition that compares if the number is equal to a string?

An example of a small test script I created to elucidate on this problem further:

```
numb_var = int(input("Test "))
if numb_var == 1 or numb_var == **str("test.")**
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failure")
```

The bolded portion is something I tried, which ultimately lead to an error I'll get to later.

I tried using a few things:

> `== str(test)`
>
> `== "tes"`
>
> `str(numb_var) == "test"`

All to no avail.

The errors just all follow "Invalid Syntax"

Is it truly impossible to do this?

Thanks, *Prior-Maxim.*

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of that line. And please format code properly. Highlight it and press the `{}` button to have it show up nice. Also note you only need to do `numb_var == "test."`. The `str()` is redundant. It will never be True though since you're converting `numb_var` to a `int`, and `"test."` can't be an int.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var = input("Test ")
numb_var = None
try:
    numb_var = int(var)
except ValueError as e:
    print('cannot be converted to an int ', e)
if numb_var == 1:
    print("Success")
elif var == 'test':
    print('Its a string')
else:
    print("Failure")
```